# Code of _gdal.pyd

Tags: python, gdal, polygonize

I want a deeper understanding of how gdal_polygonize.py works. It uses gdal.Polygonize and gdal.Polygonize refers to _gdal.pyd. Where can I see the actual algorithm where the actual polygonization happens. I assume that this is allowed since it is open source right?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably start from http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/alg/polygonize.cpp and follow it and included source files. License is MIT/X license and you can read what it means from the headers.

Comment: thanks but is that only available as cpp? I figured out that the algorithm first creates "regions" of pixels wit the same colorvalues. But how are thoes "regions" being converted to polygon-features? How are the "edges" determined? I just need the brief Idea.

Comment: pyd files on Windows are basically windows dll file and the reference are the files in C++ in [root/trunk/gdal/alg](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/alg). In Linux or Mac OS X, you compile the Python module from these files and the result is _gdal.so

Comment: GDAL is C++ and using GDAL with Python is done through SWIG bindings. All source code is there in the trac and Python stuff seems to be under http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig.